# Can I catch Exception in C in android NDK?

Tags: android, c, crash-reports

I am doing some big operation in c in android NDK. It creates a 16 MB file. my application is crashing after reading the file and doing some other operation. How can I catch Exception inside C code?

Comment: Exception in C? No, there are no exception in C.

Comment: I mean if my application crashes inside C code. can I notify the user about that.

Comment: Read more about [signals](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal). Just remember that not all "crashes" can be caught, and there are some you can not recover from.

Comment: To be more complete, the C standard doesn't support exceptions, but it is sometimes offered as an extension. For example, on Windows, errors are signaled through SEH exceptions ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft-specific_exception_handling_mechanisms ). Conclusion: The language you use doesn't support exceptions, so, unless the Android NDK documentation offers some kind of exception extension, either consider moving to C++ (hoping the "crash" you'll receive can be translated as a C++ exception), or hope that in your current C code, you can catch and recover from the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own signal handler and use it for notification or if you want to continue execution you can probably set some long jump to some higher level, but as noted by Joachim it is not possible to recover from all the exceptions.

Comment: Here's a useful link for you http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html